# NetSuite PHP Saved Search Call for "Transaction" type

Tags: netsuite

I have my standard saved search records for Items as well as Orders(**Transaction** Type) separately. The search calls works fine for Items search. But this orders search always return errors.

```
...StatusDetail Object ( [code] => INVALID_SAVEDSEARCH...
```

Is there any problem with the MODE of search that I'm using?

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$search = new ItemSearchAdvanced();
$search->savedSearchId = "658"; //internal ID of saved search
```

I know "ItemSearchAdvanced" is not the appropriate call for "Transaction" search type.
Could somebody give me a shot to fetch the Orders results?
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **TransactionSearchAdvanced**

http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/db/d4f/class_transaction_search_advanced.html

Comment: Thanks saqib! I'm using 2013_2 PHP toolkit version. And this "TransactionSearch" doesn't work for this version seems. Thoughts?

Comment: just checked the NetSuiteService.php file for 2013_2 version. TransactionSearchAdvanced object is there so it should work. Can you elaborate which error are you facing when using this object.

Comment: You were true. I mismatched with my old version. This is the error message. [code] => MEMORIZED_TRANS_ERROR                                     [message] => Attempting to access memorized transaction as a non-memorized transaction. [type] => ERROR... Where am I going wrong in this case?

Comment: I have encountered this error earlier. I think your need to add extra filter in saved search so no memorized/template transaction are fetched by it.

Comment: I surfed for a possible solution or similar guidelines. But I'm not able to get any data regarding the issue. Could you please give me a shot or any kinda reference?

Comment: As shown here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2018704/ns-memo.png there is a memorized search  filter. Turn it "No" in UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you patient replies! Your solution is the correct way!! I was actually hooking up code wise to resolve this( which wasn't correct). Now it works great! Thanks again!